# Javascript is not executing in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this javascript in my asp.net markup page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var _playLiveFeed = false;
    var _frameCounter = 0;

        var PlayLive = function () {
            var 
            timeout,
            delay = 200,
            live = document.getElementById('imgLive'),
            cache = new Image();
            divTest.style.display = 'none';
            imgPlay.style.display = 'none';
            imgLive.style.display = '';
            cache.addEventListener('load', function () {
                live.src = this.src
            }, false);

            return function PlayLiveFeed() {
                alert('hi');
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                (function loop() {
                    _frameCounter++;
                    cache.src = null;
                    cache.src = 'http://www.informedmotion.co.uk/Cloud/LiveXP.ashx?id=' + _frameCounter;
                    if (_frameCounter > 1000) {
                        _frameCounter = 0;
                    }
                    timeout = setTimeout(loop, delay);
                })();
            };
        } ()           
</script>
```

And in that same page I have a button declared as:

```
  <asp:ImageButton ID="btnLiveFeed" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ImageUrl="~/Images/flash_video_encoder.png" OnClientClick="PlayLive();return false;"/>
```

In Chrome I get my test line 'hi'.

In IE11 I get an error:

'Object' is expected.

If I just use alert('hi') on the click event itself it will display 'hi'.

If I put the alert('hi') in a new function:

```
function PlayLive2()
       {
       alert('hi');
       }
```

It also works.

So, it has to be down to the declaration of the PlayLive object. Any ideas why it does work in Chrome and not IE11 please?

thanks

Comment: What are `divTest`, `imgPlay` and `imgLive`? Are you sure that `live` is not null? Why didn't you declare the underscored variables in the private scope?

Comment: Hi, those variables are images and a div. Like I said it works in Chrome so no reason to think this was the issue. However, I follow your point I can comment those out to see what happens and report back - thanks

Comment: Hi, you are were right. I commented these out and it works. So now begets the other question what else have I done wrong :) I would give u a green tick if you repost your suggestion 0 I know it seems a trivial thing but I was stuck (and new to javascript)